# C-like array of structs in Python

Tags: python, c, struct

How can i implement a C like struct,create an array of such a struct and read such data in Python?

```
typedef struct Pair{
int first_element,second_element;
}Pair;


Pair array_of_pairs[10];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python arrays can contain anything - and they grow as needed so you don't need to put a hard-limit on the size.

Try this - it creates a `namedtuple` (good way to represent struct like things).

```
from collection import namedtuple
Pair = namedtuple("Pair", ["first", "second"])

p1 = Pair(1,2)
p2 = Pair(3,4)

list_of_pairs = [p1,p2]

print(list_of_pairs)
```

Comment: And if I,for example,want to print just the first pair or any other data from my array is it enough to just type `print(list_of_pairs[0])` just like in any python list,which i explicitly convert it into an array?

Comment: List indexing works just like in C. But you'll get an `IndexError` if you try to access anything outside the bounds of the list

Answer (score 0):

Use tuples:

```
pair = (1, 2)
first, second = pair
array_of_pair = [pair, (3, 4)]
```